# When commit records when we are inserting records from other table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have sql query like :

```
insert into dedupunclear 
  select mdnnumber,poivalue 
  from deduporiginal a 
  where exists (
    select 1 
    from deduporiginal
    where mdnnumber=a.mdnnumber and rowid<a.rowid) 
  or mdnnumber is null;
```

There is 500K records in my deduporiginal. I have put this query inside function but it will take around 3hrs to commit records to dedupunclear table.

Is there any alternative to resolve performance issue ?

When this query commit records , At some interval or after getting all results from `select` query ?

Comment: How difficult will it be for you to clean up data from a partial result that has been committed already?

Comment: @chetan - Can you post the query plan?  Are statistics on the table accurate?  Is there an index on the `mdnnumber` column? It shouldn't take anywhere near 3 hours to run that query (or to run a single `DELETE` statement that just deletes the duplicate rows if that's what you're ultimately going to do).  So I would tend to suspect that you've got a horrible plan which implies that your statistics are misleading.

Comment: It was my fault. There were other heavy oracle process loaded on server. Even Is query perfect or there is any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it the other day:

```
    delete from  table a 
     where rowid > 
            (select min(rowid) from table b 
              where   nvl(a.id, 'x') = nvl(b.id, 'x')  )
```

Instead of an insert into a dedupe table, I just deleted the rows directly from the staging table.  For a table with 1 million rows, this query worked pretty well. I was worried that the nvl function would kill the index, but it worked well enough.